# Terraform - expected cidr_block to contain a valid Value, got: 0.0.0.0 with err: invalid CIDR address: 0.0.0.0

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-security-group

I'm going through the [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/security_group) and they have `aws_vpc.main.cidr_block` in a resource. I defined the resource which isn't in the documentation but I the following error.

`Terraform - expected cidr_block to contain a valid Value, got: 0.0.0.0 with err: invalid CIDR address: 0.0.0.0`

Why is it invalid? I want to allow ingress all source IP to be able to reach 443.

File vpc.tf

```
resource "aws_vpc" "main" {
    id = "vpc-0da86af9876e72d66c"
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
}
```

File test.tf

```
resource "aws_security_group" "allow_tls" {
  name        = "allow_tls"
  description = "Allow TLS inbound traffic"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.main.id

  ingress {
    description = "TLS from VPC"
    from_port   = 443
    to_port     = 443
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = [aws_vpc.main.cidr_block]
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "allow_tls"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VPC is your network, it's not a firewall rule like you already defined on `aws_security_group` resource. If you want to expose the HTTP server to the world, the `cidr_blocks` in the `ingress` block will be `0.0.0.0/0` as well.

`cidr_block` parameter of `aws_vpc` defines the range and size of your network, like `10.0.0.0/16`, `172.31.0.0/16` and `192.168.0.0/24`.

You can read more about VPCs and subnets on [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Subnets.html).

You also don't pass the `id`. This is auto-generated by AWS.

Example:

```
resource "aws_vpc" "main" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
}
```

Check the [terraform docs for aws_vpc](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/vpc) that lists all arguments supported.

Comment: What if I have to use an existing vpc?

Comment: You can just pass the ID of the existing VPC in the `vpc_id` parameter for the security group, if you don't have that defined in terraform you can hardcode or pass as terraform paramater.

If you meant you already have a VPC and want to start managing in terraform, you can import via `terraform import`